# Bullet ApplyCentralImpulse does not work in the y and z axis. After moving from vs 2015 to vs 2017 and cmake its not working

Tags: c++, bulletphysics

```
Body->applyCentralImpulse(btVector(x, y, z));
```

does not apply forces in `y` and `z` direction. Only `x` value is taken.

I have also tried by commenting all `setLinearFactor` and `setAngularFactor` functions. But I am not able to get this thing to work. The debug drawer shows the translation in only +x or -ve x.

Please Help

Comment: Show the code for `applyCentralImpulse()`. Did you move from a 32 bit to a 64 bit machine as well?

Comment: I found the source..Have you tried asking [bulletphysics/bullet3 @ github](https://github.com/bulletphysics/bullet3/issues)?

Comment: That is the code. lets say x value is 15.0 and y value is 10.0. It moves in x direction only in debug drawer. It is running on 64 bit Debug config. Before too it was running on 64 bit but i was using bullets static library. Now i have added all the code to my current CMAKE.

Comment: You should probably [create a ticket](https://github.com/bulletphysics/bullet3/issues/new) and describe your issue there..